# スクロールバーを使用しようとすると、エラーになります。 AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Scrollber'

Tags: python

何故エラーになるのかわかりません。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_28456/666825894.py in <module>
     26 txtbox = tk.Text(frame,width = 60,height = 20)
     27 
---> 28 yscroll = tk.Scrollber(frame, orient = tk.VERTICAL,command = txtbox.yview)
     29 
     30 txtbox['yscrollcommand'] = yscroll.set

AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Scrollber'
```

**ソースコード:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def sub_window():
    mini_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    
    button2 = tk.Button(mini_window, text = 'Push2')
    button2.pack(padx = 50, pady = 25)
    

    mini_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    
    button2 = tk.Button(mini_window, text = 'Push3')
    button2.pack(padx = 50, pady = 25)


root =tk.Tk()

button2 = tk.Button(root, text = 'Push1', command = sub_window)
button2.pack(padx = 50, pady = 25)

frame = ttk.Frame(root,padding = 5)
frame.pack(padx = 5,pady = 5)

txtbox = tk.Text(frame,width = 60,height = 20)

yscroll = tk.Scrollber(frame, orient = tk.VERTICAL,command = txtbox.yview)**

txtbox['yscrollcommand'] = yscroll.set

yscroll.pack(side =tk.RIGHT,fill = tk.Y)



txtbox.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: typoですね。`'Scrollber'`ではなく`'Scrollbar'`です。

Comment: 凡ミスでしたが、思い込んでいて気づきませんでした。ありがとうございます。